# Limit user reaction to message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm building a simple ***poll bot*** for Discord in JavaScript, right now I'm trying to implement max number of reactions per user to a message.

*For example*, suppose we have the following options for a poll question:

> The Question?
>
> 1. Option A
> 2. Option B
> 3. Option C
> 4. Option D
> 5. Option E

Each "option" is a reaction to the message given from the bot, I want to make sure that a user ***cannot react*** to *more than* `3` of those options.

- My train of thought was to make a `messageReactionAdd` listener and
  then when the user reacted for the `4th time`, remove the last
  reaction, sending him a message like "You've already voted `3 times`,
  please remove a reaction to vote again".
- Still, I'm stuck trying to navigate through the objects to find the
  total reaction count *per user* I can find the total reaction count
  *per emoji* but that's not what I need.

Could someone give me some insight on this?

**EDIT**

Code used to send messages:

```
Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(0x6666ff)
                .setTitle(question)
                .setDescription(optionsList);

                message.channel.send(Embed).then(messageReaction => {

                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
                    messageReaction.react(emojiAlphabet[i][0]);
                }

                message.delete().catch(console.error);
              });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const {Collection} = require('discord.js')

// the messages that users can only react 3 times with
const polls = new Set()
// Collection<Message, Collection<User, number>>: stores how many times a user has reacted on a message
const reactionCount = new Collection()

// when you send a poll add the message the bot sent to the set:
polls.add(message)

client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  // edit: so that this does not run when the bot reacts
  if (user.id === client.user.id) return

  const {message} = reaction

  // only do the following if the message is one of the polls
  if (polls.has(message)) {
    // if message hasn't been added to collection add it
    if (!reactionCount.get(message)) reactionCount.set(message, new Collection())
    // reaction counts for this message
    const userCount = reactionCount.get(message)
    // add 1 to the user's reaction count
    userCount.set(user, (userCount.get(user) || 0) + 1)

    if (userCount.get(user) > 3) {
      reaction.users.remove(user)
      // <@!id> mentions the user (using their nickname if they have one)
      message.channel.send(`<@!${user.id}>, you've already voted 3 times, please remove a reaction to vote again.`)
    }
  }
})

client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
  // edit: so that this does not run when the bot reacts
  if (user.id === client.user.id) return

  const {message} = reaction
  const userCount = reactionCount.get(message)
  // subtract 1 from user's reaction count
  if (polls.has(message)) userCount.set(user, reactionCount.get(message).get(user) - 1)
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much cherryblossom :-) Another question while i try to implement the code, with the client.on('messageReactionAdd') i get double the calls for reactions added by the bot, can i exclude them in any way from the parsing both in the messageReactionAdd and messageReactionRemove? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ManuelCelli Yes you can use `if (user.id === client.user.id) return`. I edited my post.

Comment: thank you again for your help :-) I'm having some issues in adding the message to the polls const,i've updated the question with the code i use to create the message.

Comment: Managed to resolve it, used polls.add(client.user.lastMessage)

Comment: @ManuelCelli You can also do `message.channel.send(Embed).then(messageReaction => polls.add(messageReaction))`.